# Program freezes under gdb when exception occurs

Tags: debugging, exception, gcc, gdb, freeze

I compiled with g++ a simple test program:

```
int main()
{
  try
  {
    printf("before\n");
    throw 1;
  }
  catch(int i)
  {
    printf("catched int\n");
  }
  catch(...)
  {
    printf("catched(...)\n");
  }
}
```

Normally works ok with or without debug info included.
But when debugged with gdb it always hangs on "throw 1;" line so I'm not able to debug programs, that normally throws exceptions.
The last information from debugger is:

```
Catchpoint 1 (exception thrown), 0x00007ffff7b8f9e0 in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
```

My compilation and linking options:

```
g++ -Wshadow -Wunreachable-code -Wswitch-enum -Wswitch-default -Wextra -Wall  -pg -g -m64    -c main.cpp

g++ -o exec/exception_problem obj/main.o -pg
```

My environment:
ubuntu 10.10, 64bit; 
g++/gcc 4.4.5; 
gdb 7.2; 
debugged under codeblocks svn rev 7440

Any ideas what is the problem?

Additional info:
Last two lines of gdb log are:

```
Catchpoint 1 (exception thrown), 0x00007ffff7b8f9e0 in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
>>>>>>cb_gdb:
```

The last character in log is colon. 
gdb commandline:

```
/usr/bin/gdb -nx -fullname -quiet -args exec/exception_problem
```

I did not found any *gdbinit* in my home directory; global gdbinit is empty. Is it possible that codeblocks prepares specific gdbinit and puts it to gdb?

Best regards for all.

Comment: How does it "hang" exactly? Do you get a (gdb) prompt? What happens if you press Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Z?

Comment: Ctrl+C closes program and terminal window, but debugging session in condeblocks is still active (no new info in debug log). After that I'm able to end session normally with stop button.

Answer (score 1):

> `Catchpoint 1 (exception thrown) ...`

Is there something in your `.gdbinit` that you haven't told us about? (Perhaps `catch throw` ?)

Is the `Catchpoint 1` *really* the last line that GDB prints? Here is what I see:

```
Reading symbols from /tmp/a.out...done.
Catchpoint 1 (throw)
(gdb) run
before
Catchpoint 1 (exception thrown), __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw (obj=0x602090, tinfo=0x601060, dest=0) at ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:70
70  ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc: No such file or directory.
    in ../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc
(gdb) c
catched int
[Inferior 1 (process 16008) exited normally]
(gdb) q
```

Comment: In fact real last two lines are:
Catchpoint 1 (exception thrown), 0x00007ffff7b8f9e0 in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
>>>>>>cb_gdb:
The last character in log is colon.
gdb commandline:
/usr/bin/gdb -nx -fullname  -quiet -args exec/exception_problem

I did not found any *gdbinit* in my home directory; global gdbinit is empty.

Is it possible that codeblocks prepares specific gdbinit and puts it  to gdb?